# "Application failed codesign verification." -- was working until I changed some build settings in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing

My app has been compiling fine, but trying to fix something I fiddled with some of the build settings, and now I'm getting an "application failed codesign verification" error.  So it seems like it's not a certificate issue, but I don't know what the right settings are or what to do to fix this.

Here are some screen caps:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any thoughts about what I can to to get everything copacetic again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this (and many other errors like it) quite a few times as well, but I never seem to remember what exactly fixes what.

First, you should go to **Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme** and check that the **Build Configuration** in the **"Run appName.app"-tab** is set to **Debug**, and not to release.

If that's not the problem, you should just try **Product->Clean** and then build again.
You're sure you've set the correct provisioning profiles in the **Build Settings** in **BOTH** Project and Target?

Side note: Restarting XCode has proven helpful a couple of times as well..

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I had the wrong settings for "Validate Built Product."  Here, in case anybody is having the same problem, are the ones that got rid of the error.

[image]

**EDIT:**  Except of course now it's back.

**EDIT:**  Looks like restarting, as per the answer below, did the trick...at least for now.  Fingers crossed....